# 1 filenames = [] 2 ----> 3 for file in os.zipfile('images.zip'):

Tags: image, operating-system, pickle, filenames, tqdm

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 3>()
1 filenames = []
2
----> 3 for file in os.zipfile('images.zip'):
4     filenames.append(os.path.join('images.zip',zipfile))

NameError: name 'os' is not defined

for file in os.listdir('images'):
filenames.append(os.path.join('images',file))

feature_list = []

for file in tqdm(filenames):
feature_list.append(extract_features(file,model))

pickle.dump(feature_list,open('embeddings.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(filenames,open('filenames.pkl','wb'))